# Promisifying listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, listeners

I was a huge promise chain, however I realized that one of the functions returns an object that has listeners and react to callbacks like

```
object.on('data', function(err, data) {
     //do something
});

object.on('exit', function(err, data) {
     //do something
});
```

I was wondering if there was a way to work this using promises and turn them into thenables. Is there no alternative to rewriting my entire promise chain to use callbacks?

Comment: Suggested duplicate shows code converting callbacks and promises to each other. For node.js specific conversion check what promise library you use and adopt conversion code accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you wrap the object?

```
var promiseForObjectData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  // Note that you can't promisify data, because it gets called multiple times.
  object.on('data', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    //do something
  });

  object.on('exit', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    return resolve(...whatever...);
  });

});
```